# How to install ubuntu with a kernel version compatible with site recovery on an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, replication

I am going through some Azure training and want to try out the Azure Site Recovery functionality for an Azure Ubuntu 20.04 VM.

The VM is created with the latest standard Ubuntu 20.04 image; replication is enabled but failed:

Error ID: `151113`
Error Message:

> This version of mobility service doesn't support the operating system
> kernel version (5.13.0-1023-azure) running on the source machine.
> Please refer the list of operating systems supported by Azure Site
> Recovery : https://aka.ms/a2a_supported_linux_os_versions

[image: screenshot of the error message]

As this is the most basic configuration I can imagine, I wonder how to set this up correctly so it works.

These are the official instructions I found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-quickstart

The VM is a `Standard B1ms (1 vcpu, 2 GiB memory)`. I had started with a smaller one first, but then read that 1GB memory is minimum and upgraded the VM to B1ms.

The kernel version of an out-of-the-box Ubuntu 20.04 installation is `5.13.0-1023-azure`; all the supported kernel versions are in the `5.4.*` version numbers according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-support-matrix#supported-ubuntu-kernel-versions-for-azure-virtual-machines.

Answer (score 0):

The Error you are getting because the updated `mobility service version` is not compatible with the `old version of kernal`. You have update to lastet `version` of `kernal`.

> To support latest Linux kernels within 15 days of release, Azure Site
> Recovery rolls out hot fix patch on top of latest mobility agent
> version. This fix is rolled out in between two major version releases.
> To update to latest version of mobility agent (including hot fix
> patch) follow steps mentioned in this [**article**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/service-updates-how-to#azure-vm-disaster-recovery-to-azure). This patch is
> currently rolled out for mobility agents used in Azure to Azure DR
> scenario.

***Note : Before upgrading operating system/kernel versions, verify if the target version is supported Site Recovery.
Review [**available**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-whats-new) updates to find out what you want to upgrade***